# ReactJS. I can't submit image through Axios to Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, reactjs, django, axios

I really need your help.
I'm trying to send image through Axios to Django Rest Framework field for my project but I'm always facing this error **'The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'**

Here my code :

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    pictureImage = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True, verbose_name="pictureImage")
```

serializer.py

```
from api.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
import base64
from uuid import uuid4
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'pictureImage')


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        return token


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','pictureImage')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            pictureImage=validated_data['pictureImage']
        )
        
        user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from api.models import User
from api.serializer import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        '/api/token/',
        '/api/register/',
        '/api/token/refresh/'
    ]
    return Response(routes)
```

Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Auth.css'
import axios from 'axios';

function Register() {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        pictureImage: ''
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formDataObject = new FormData();

        for (const key in formData) {
            formDataObject.append(key, formData[key]);
        }
        try {
            const instance = axios.create({
                baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000'
            });
            const response = await instance.post('/api/register/', formDataObject);
            console.log('Inscription réussie:', response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error.response.data);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='form-container'>
            <h1 className='title-page'>INSCRIPTION</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <div className="box-decoration">
                    <input
                        name="pictureImage"
                        type="file"
                        id="pictureImage"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
                        value={formData.pictureImage}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='group'>
                    <button type='submit'>Inscription</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Register;
```

I've tried to use FormData() and I also added encType="multipart/form-data" attribute on my registration form but I still have this error as you can see below.
[image]

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong.
I'm really desperate.
Thank you in advance.

Sincerely

Comment: Are able to send an image with something like Postman, to be sure your Backend is okay?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Django side but I used JSON.stringify function to send photo to Spring Backend then decode image with Base64.

**> Mentioned Code****

```
await fetch('http://${ipAdress}:${port}/takePhoto/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ photoDataUrl: this.photoDataUrl, stationCode: stationCode, stationSource: stationSource })

        })
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you show me how did you do